# what does this command do? cat f1 f2 .. > f1

Tags: linux

f1 and f2 are two files, I want to know what does this two commands in linux,  cat f1 f2 .. > f1 and       less f1 f2 …>f2 . I dont have linux in my computer to test them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
[expalainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cat+f1+f2+..+%3E+f1)
to understand shell lines that may be hard to google.

And these days you don't even need to install Linux on your machine,
you can run Linux directly in your browser - for example, to try
Debian:
https://distrotest.net/index.php?module=systems&submodule=run&id=1068633